# In what practical case bool(std::ifstream) != std::ifstream::good()?

Tags: c++, io, stream, eof

I would like to know in what case we can have :

```
bool(std::ifstream) != std::ifstream::good()
```

The difference is that `bool(std::ifstream)` does not test the `eof` bit whereas `std::ifstream::good()` tests it. But practically, the `eof` bit is raised if one try to read something after the end of the file. But as soon as you try to do this I think that either `fail` or `bad` bit is also set.

Consequently in what case you can only raise the `eof` bit ?

Comment: You can manually set the eof bit independently of the other error flags, but I'm not sure under what circumstances you would do so. `std::ifstream::setstate(std::ios::eofbit)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, whenever you encounter the end of a file without attempting to read behind it. Consider a file "one.txt" which contains exactly one single '1' character.

Example for unformatted input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char chars[255] = {0};
    ifstream f("one.txt");
    f.getline(chars, 250, 'x');
    cout << f.good() << " != " << bool(f) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> 0 != 1
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Example for formatted input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ifstream f("one.txt");
    int i; f >> i;
    cout << f.good() << " != " << bool(f) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> 0 != 1
>   Press any key to continue . . .