# C++ istream EOF does not guarantee failbit?

Tags: c++, eof

I read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555371/in-what-practical-case-boolstdifstream-stdifstreamgood) on Stack Overflow where the eofbit for the istream `file` is set but the failbit is not. In that case file is true and file.eof() is true but file.good() is false. For example with a file exactly one byte in size:

```
ifstream file("one.txt");
assert( file.is_open() );
for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
{
    char chars[255] = {0};
    file.getline(chars, 2);
    //file.read( chars, 2 );

    cout << "file: " << !!file << endl;
    cout << "good: " << file.good() << endl;
    cout << "eof: " << file.eof() << endl;
    cout << "fail: " << file.fail() << endl;
    cout << "bad: " << file.bad() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is the output:

```
file: 1
good: 0
eof: 1
fail: 0
bad: 0

file: 0
good: 0
eof: 1
fail: 1
bad: 0
```

If I comment out the getline() and use read() instead, I get this:

```
file: 0
good: 0
eof: 1
fail: 1
bad: 0

file: 0
good: 0
eof: 1
fail: 1
bad: 0
```

In both cases I'm reading past the end of the file in the loop's first iteration. Why is one EOF and fail and one isn't? The answer in the other thread says "whenever you encounter the end of a file without attempting to read behind it." read behind it? What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `eofbit` is set by the `getline` method if it stops reading because it hits the end of the stream (file), rather than by finding the delimiter character. `getline` does *not* set the `failbit` in that case, which is logical because it didn't fail: it read some data.

Once the `eofbit` is set, the next read operation on that stream will set the `failbit`, because the internal sentry function, called at the start of just about every input operation, will set `failbit` if `eofbit` is set.

In general, the `eofbit` "indicates that an input operation reached the end of an input sequence", while `failbit` "indicates that an input operation failed to read the expected characters" (both quotes are from the C++ standard, section `[ios.types]`; §27.5.3.1, table 124, in the latest draft I have lying around.) As the `getline` example shows, it is quite possible for an input operation to read the end of an input sequence, while still reading something.

Another, somewhat less formal -- and therefore possibly incorrect -- way of looking at this is that `eofbit` is set if the read operation reached the end of the file, whereas the `failbit` is set if the read operation could not read the minimum number of characters it required. The `2` in the calls to `getline` and `read` mean different things; in `getline`, it is the *maximum* number of characters for the input operation (the minimum number is 1); in the case of `read`, it is the *precise* number of characters.